# yii editable function is displaying js error

Tags: javascript, yii

I am using yii's editable.Editable function. I am getting below js error from this `Cannot read property 'editableSuccess' of undefined`

Here is the code I am using for this purpose. It displays the text field on click. But while clicking on save button. I get above error.

```
$this->widget('editable.Editable', array(
 'type' => 'text',
 'name' => 'user_name',
 'text' => 'John',
 'url' => 'general/index',
 'title' => 'Enter Name',
 'placement' => 'right'
));
```

Comment: show more code .. this in not enough ..

Comment: @scaisEdge I have updated my quesiton

Comment: which `js` file is the error pointing to. and the error is it `editableSuccess` or `editable.Success` ?